# How to include pixels excluded by MASK in GRASS GIS?

Tags: python, raster, masking, grass-6.4

I have a 150km x 150km raster layer of elevation. I'm running a cell-by-cell PyGRASS script, with one step that considers all neighboring cells within a fairly large circular radius (25km). To account for edge effects, I've sub-divided my large region into four 50x50km raster tiles - each created with a raster MASK - factoring out the outer most 25km in each cardinal direction.

I'm trying to figure out a way to include pixels *outside* of these MASKs created in GRASS GIS. Basically, I'd like to use the MASK as a processing extent, but I don't want to nullify the values in the factored out 25km. They should be included in each neighborhood calculation for cells along the inner border of my mask.

I have quite a number of these 150x150 raster tiles, so I haven't just run my script across the entire region simply to save computational time. Any ideas as to how I can run my script on a subset of this larger raster, without losing values outside the MASKed region?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is (too?) late, but I have the same problem and 'partially' resolve with `v.buffer` with certain distance, and then `r.mask` over the layer buffer.